# Layering SVGs for use with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers, svg

I have the following situation:
I have a tool that spits out a number of SVGs¹. I need a script that will convert these into a single Inkscape file such the contents of each original SVG go into a single layer in the final SVG.

I could go to Python and try to parse the SVG structure, but I suspect an easier method exists.

For example: I have 3 SVG files, `A.svg, B.svg` and `C.svg`
The result should be one SVG file with three layers, first layer containing `A.svg`, second with `B.svg`, and so on. Naming and stack of layers is not critical

<sup>¹ For some context, the source SVGs are the drawings for the multiple layers of a printed circuit board: I will be adding annotations and using the resulting circuit board in a classroom. The annotations are few but the task has to be repeated for a number of different boards.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I just made a 3-layer file to investigate the structure, each layer containing a simple geometric figure.

The result has a header, which ends in

```
  </metadata>
```

Then, for each layer, a block (here shown for layer 1):

```
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <CONTENT/>
  </g>
```

The part of CONTENT would be one of your files, stripped from its header and from its SVG-close-tag.

Ended with the overall SVG-close-tag.

```
</svg>
```

Okay, what would be the most comfortable way to use such a script? You have to specify a filename for the final result and the files for the layers. It could be convenient to work with file name patterns in the shell like

```
layerize.sh result.svg board*.svg
```

**Caution:** 
This is a raw solution which might fail under special conditions and is not sanitized against common errors, like missing or wrong parameters. It might fail with duplicated Group-IDs and so on from different files.

My first approach worked for simple figures, but not for gradients and so on. So I have a new workflow:

- Open a new, empty SVG file.
- import all the images you like to distribute over different layers at once. This should include all gradients, filters and definition you need.
- save this file as "layerstemplate.svg"

Now use this modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$1
shift

test -e $result && echo "file exists!" && exit 1

# takes everything, up to the closing "metadata" tag from the template:
header () {
    sed -n '1,/<\/metadata>/p' ./layertemplate.svg
}

count=0
layer () {
    ((count +=1))
    echo -e "   <g
    inkscape:label=\"Layer $count\"
    inkscape:groupmode=\"layer\"
    id=\"layer$count\">"
     sed '1,/<\/metadata>/d;$d' "$1"
     echo -e "  </g>"
}

header > "$result" 
# iterates over all (remaining) parameters
for f 
do
    layer "$f" >> "$result"
done
echo "</svg>" >> "$result"
```

I did not try it with sources, which use layers themselves and have no idea      how I would handle it. So far, I don't plan on improving this further, but feel free to make suggestions, to criticize it and ask questions.